# Generate Existing PDF Using pdf-fill-form, Filling Checkbox Values

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

I've generated an array of fields using [pdf-fill-form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-fill-form)

```
pdfFillForm.read('test.pdf')
```

and, for checkboxes, it returns two fields with identical `name` values with unique `id`s ie

```
{ "name": "cbexample", "page": 0, "value": false, "id": 65576, "type": "checkbox" },
{ "name": "cbexample", "page": 0, "value": false, "id": 65577, "type": "checkbox" },
```

How do I set the value correctly?
normally it just takes a `"key": value` to fill a field ie

```
pdfFillForm.write('test.pdf', { "myField": "myField fill value" })
```

I've tried the following methods:

```
cbexample: true,
cbexample: false
-----------------
cbexample: {"id": 65576, "value": true}
-----------------
cbexample: 'yes'
-----------------
cbexample: 1
```

but nothing works as anticipated.
Has anyone used this or any other libraries?

The object I'm passing to the `pdfFillForm.write` function looks like:

```
{
 "cbexample": "value"
 "txtexample": "value",
 "txtexample2": "value",
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to edit the results from `pdfFillForm.read('test.pdf')` something like `{ "name": "cbexample", "page": 0, "value": true, "id": 65577, "type": "checkbox" }`? If so I guess you could filter the object for the specific `id` and edit the `value` property.

Comment: That method is just for reading the values. I've written them to a static document so I can easily refer to it. My object for the write function looks like {"cbexample": "value", "txtexample": "value", "txtexample2": "value" }

Comment: Though maybe I could try mapping over the results from that function and see if it still works. The documentation for pdf-fill-form doesn't go very in depth.

Comment: has anyone tried this on Windows? In docs it says that it is not supported - https://github.com/tpisto/pdf-fill-form#windows

Answer (score 0):

After looking through the pdf-form-fill source code, the correct value is "true" as in a string with the letters t,r,u,e in them not the boolean value true.

So in your example:
cbexample: "true"